# Create specific page for warnings in doxygen

Tags: doxygen

Throughout my code I have added `\warning my text` labels for documentation and I would like to see all of these warnings compiled in one spot similar to `\todo` and `\bug` labels.

How do I go about adding these to the *Related Pages* tab in my generated documentation?

I'm assuming I need to edit and link the layout file as shown [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html#layout) however having not messed with xml much I'm not sure how to proceed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I create a section inside config

```
ALIASES                = "req=\xrefitem req \\"Requirements\" \\"Requirements\"" \
                         "note=\xrefitem note \\"Notes\" \\"Notes\"" \
                         "dev=\xrefitem dev \\"Developments\" \\"Developments\"" \
                         "warning=\xrefitem warning \\"Warnings\" \\"Warnings\""
```

a new page inside "related" will be created

See also in the doxygen documentation about [Custom Commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/custcmd.html).